# How do I display youtube videos with lytebox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, embed, lightbox2

I have a youtube embed code here: `<iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/F_sbusEUz5w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

that I'd like to display using a modified version of lightbox 2 called lytebox, found here:
http://www.dolem.com/lytebox/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

`<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/F_sbusEUz5w" rel="lyteframe" rev="width: 560px; height: 349px; scrolling: auto;">Click here to view the video.</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest one is : Save your iframe in different html page and load this page by lytebox

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/yourpage.html" rel="lyteframe" title="title" 
rev="lytebox styling">Your video name</a>
```

You can also use embed link directly instead of page